# Observable/Subscription in Angular 2 service for passing data between 2 components

Tags: angularjs, rxjs, observable, angular2-services, subscription

I am trying to read a value from a Component A( Modal window) which happens on selection from a set of values. Once the ok button is pressed on Component A, I want the value to be passed to Component B ( Page component). I have a service for this and followed the example specified here [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/35568924#35568924)

I see that the subject updates on .next(). But from my subscriber , i don't see the updated value when i am trying to access it from Component B.

Please help me find what exactly is the issue here ,

XService.ts

```
       import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
        import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
        import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

        @Injectable()
        export class XService {
            constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

            // Observable Item source
            public _adModalSelectedSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('w');

            // Observable Item stream
            selectedRow$ = this._adModalSelectedSource.asObservable();

            // service command
            changeNav(string) {
                this._adModalSelectedSource.next(string);
            }

        }
```

Component A.ts

```
        btnClick(btn) {
            if (btn.id === 'ok') {
                this.XService.changeNav('yes');
                this.activeModal.close(this.selectedRows);
            } else {
                this.activeModal.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

ComponentB.ts

```
    import { Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
    import { NgbDropdownConfig, NgbTabset } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
    import { Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

    import { XService} from '../../x/x.service';

    import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

    @Component ({
      selector: 'compb',
      templateUrl: './compb.html',
      styleUrls: ['./compb.component.scss'],
      providers: [xService, NgbTabset]
    })

    export class ComponentB {

        xService: XService;
        test: any;
        subscription:Subscription;
        route: any;
        tabs: any;
        subTabs: { all: 'all', problemMachines : 'problem_machines' };

      constructor( X:XService, tabs: NgbTabset, route: ActivatedRoute) {
          this.xModalService = X;
          this.route = route;
          this.tabs = tabs;
          this.subTabs = { all: 'all', problemMachines : 'problem_machines' };
      }

      SelectHandler(data) {
            if (data.item.id === 'XXX') {
                this.XService.openModal().then(() => {
                    **console.log('test value'+ this.test);**
                    console.log('close');
                    //this._loadData();
                });
            } 
       }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.filterText = '';
        this.subscription = this.xService.selectedRow$.subscribe(test => this.test = test);

      }



      ngOnDestroy() {
        //on destroy hook
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      }

    }
```

SelectHandler is the event handler for button on which the modal( Component A opens) user picks a value which then needs to be available for Component B( page) to process on.

In Component B I do put the subscription in onINit() , but this.test does not have the changed value.

Any inputs  will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you have **two instances** of the XService, one for Component A and one for Component B, because you are setting that on the provider property of the component. You should do a moudle wrapping this two components and set as a provider the XService there. with that, there will be only one instance of XService shared with the both components.

The module should be something like this:

```
@NgModule({
imports:         [],
declarations:    [
    ComponentA,
    ComponentB
],
entryComponents: [
    ComponentA,
    ComponentB
],
providers:       [XService],
exports:         []
}
)export class MyModule {}
```

Hope this help.